# Word wrap with DrawTextEx in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I need to draw text inside the rect. But when the text is long, it's clip out the extra text. I need to wrap the text, so that extra part of text which don't fits in the first line should goes to the next line.

I have google it, there was a suggestion to use DrawTextEx() with DT_CALCRECT flag instead of DrawText(). But still it's not working, when I uses this flag I am not getting the text.

```
DRAWTEXTPARAMS lpDTParams;
lpDTParams.cbSize        = sizeof(lpDTParams);
lpDTParams.iLeftMargin   = 1;
lpDTParams.iRightMargin  = 1;
lpDTParams.iTabLength    = 4;
lpDTParams.uiLengthDrawn = 0;

pDC->DrawTextExA(sTemp, rc, DT_NOCLIP|DT_CENTER|DT_WORDBREAK|DT_CALCRECT, &lpDTParams);
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well, it depends how you did set your CRect. DT_CALCRECT will increase its bottom side to fit all lines of text but you have to give enough width. I suggest to do not use DT_CALCRECT if you have a fixed area where you want to draw (and consider what will happen with DT_NOCLIP if text is too big). Finally check the CRect content, it **must** be big enough to fit text width.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you pass DT_CALCRECT no text is drawn, it is simply calculating how tall the rect would need to be to fit it all.  You need to call DrawTextEx again to draw it using the calculated rect.

Comment: DT_CALCRECT will be used for getting the new rect. And again calling it will this function after removing the DT_CALCRECT will draw the text. 

But now the text is coming, but the line didn't gets wrapped, It extends the rect boundary, but not coming on nect line.

Can you please comment on this, why the text id not moving to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to calculate rectangle.

Use following flags: DT_LEFT | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK.

One piece of the advice:

Do not use UNICODE or ANSI specific function names.

Depending on your project settings compiler will pick up the right version. This way your application is portable.

Comment: Thanks JohnCz

Using DT_EDITCONTROL slove the purpose.